# Django Celery task to process csv - model not saving

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-celery

I encountered some behavior in trying to save changes to my model during a celery task but changes do not commit. I have a model that keeps a record of uploads by users, once the file is uploaded, a celery task is run to process the csv and save the results of the process into the database, e.g. process status, time processed, number of records processed etc.

In models.py, I have the following methods:

```
def import_records_data(self):
    total_records = 0
    with self.filepath.file as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(reader, None) # skip header
        for row in reader:
            # process record
            total_records += 1
    return total_records

def process(self):
    self.date_start_processing = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    try:
        # process upload data,
        records_processed = self.import_records_data()
    except Exception, e:
        self._mark_failed(unicode(e))
    else:
        self._mark_processed(num_records=records_processed)

def _mark_processed(self, num_records, description=None):
    self.status = self.PROCESSED
    self.date_end_processing = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    self.num_records = num_records
    self.processing_description = description
    self.save()

def _mark_failed(self, description):
    self.status = self.FAILED
    self.processing_description = description
    self.save()

 def was_processing_successful(self):
    return self.status == self.PROCESSED
```

When _mark_processed or _mark_failed is called, the changes are not saved into the database when `self.save()` is called. This method is called from tasks.py:

```
@task(name='csv-process-upload')
def process_upload(upload_id):
    upload = Upload.objects.get(id=upload_id)
    upload.process()

    if upload.was_processing_successful():
        message_user(
            upload.user,
            "Your upload '%s' was processed successfully, %s records processed" % (
                upload.filename,
                upload.num_records))
    else:
        message_user(
            upload.user,
            "Your upload '%s' could not be processed, error message: %s" % (
                upload.filename,
                upload.processing_description,))
```

What could be preventing the model from saving? When I debug `_mark_processed` in shell and type `self.save()`, the changes are reflected in the database.

Comment: How are you triggering the celery task?  If its triggered in a Django view, the initial model save/creation can be held in a transaction and not yet visible to celery when the task runs.

Comment: Yes, it is triggered via a view. What should I do then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [django celery transactions](https://github.com/chrisdoble/django-celery-transactions) to call your tasks to ensure your views complete the transaction before triggering the task to execute.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it seemed like previous celery tasks did not complete and I had to purge them manually. The task was able to run successfully after that without relying on django-celery-transactions.

Comment: Sounds good.  Check out celery-flower (along with `--events`) for a nice web admin for monitoring your celery workers and task queue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Shall take a look at it.